# Is this case handled by distribution theory?

Tags: notation, distribution-theory

I want to express a distribution, $f(x)$, that has the following properties:
$$\int_{-\infty}^x f(x') \operatorname{d}x' = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & x \le 0 \\
  \frac{1}{x} & x > 0.
\end{array}\right. = \frac{\Theta(x)}{x},$$
where $\Theta(x)$ is a unit step function. Formally, I would guess that I could just take the derivative using the standard rules to get:
$$f(x) = -\frac{\Theta(x)}{x^2} + \frac{\delta(x)}{x}.$$

The problem I have is that integrating the second equation above to recover the required property runs into an apparent $\infty - \infty$ ambiguity. Is this ambiguity handled in distribution theory in some particular way? Is this, perhaps, related in some way to the [Cauchy principle value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), for example?

Right now, my best guess for how to write $f$ to make it unambiguously have the needed property is to write it as:
$$f(x) = \lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\left(-\frac{1}{x^2} + \left[\frac{1}{x}\right] \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) \sigma(x,s), $$
where $\sigma(x,s)$ is a signmoid that satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sigma(x,s)}{x^2} = 0$, $\sigma(x,s)=0$ if $x \le 0$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sigma(x,s) = 1$, $\lim_{s\rightarrow 0^+} \sigma(x,s) = \Theta(x)$, and the limit is understood, formally, to be delayed until after an integral is taken, the same way many think about the delta function. For example:
$$\sigma(x,s) = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(-\frac{\ln(x/s)}{s\sqrt{2}}\right)  \Theta(x),$$
where $\mathrm{erfc}$ is the the standard [complimentary error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$\ln_+(x) = \begin{cases}\ln x, & x>0 \\ 0, & x\leq 0\end{cases}$$
This is in $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and thus a distribution. The derivative of it obviously satisfies
$$\ln_+'(x) = \begin{cases}\frac1x, & x>0 \\ 0, & x\leq 0\end{cases}$$
so you can take
$$f = \ln_+''.$$

I understand that you want it expressed in a more explicit form, but that's not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity is not handled by symmetry arguments as in the Cauchy PV. $f$ should be thought of as having an consistently infinite integral against a test function. You could still use distributions, but the result might not be meaningful.

Distributions are defined as a continuous linear functional against a space of test functions. We can suggestively write the evaluation of $T$ against $\phi$ as $\int T(x) \phi(x)dx.$

Let $\beta$ be a bump function with $\beta(0)=1$ and $\beta(x)=\beta(-x)$ and $\beta''(0)=-1.$

In the case of the Cauchy PV, distributions $T$ satisfying $\int T\phi=\int \tfrac 1 x \phi$ wherever the right-hand-side is integrable are determined up to adding a multiple of $\delta_0.$
This is because we can decompose any test function $\phi$ as $\phi(x)=\phi(0)\beta(x)+(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\beta(x)),$ and the value of $T$ against $\phi(x)-\phi(0)\beta(x)$ is uniquely determined.
Imposing $\int T \beta=0$ gives a unique solution, and this condition is natural because $1/x$ is odd and $\beta$ is even.

Consider the symmetric problem $\int_{\infty}^x g(x)=|x|^{-1}.$
(To get your $f$ from $\tfrac 1 2 g$, add half the derivative of the Cauchy PV.)
By integration by parts we look for a weak solution $T$ satisfying $\int T \phi=-\int |x|^{-1}\phi'(x)$ wherever the right-hand-side is integrable.
This determines $T$ uniquely up to a multiple of $\delta'_0.$ But now a symmetry argument doesn't determine the coefficient of $\delta'_0,$ because $T$ should be odd, so symmetry doesn't show that $\int T\beta'$ is necessarily zero.

In fact $\int |x|^{-1}\beta''(x)$ is negative in a neighborhood of zero, and integrable outside that neighborhood. So the integral is unambiguously $-\infty.$ Depending on the application you could still define a distribution which evaluates this integral as a constant $\Lambda,$ and hope to derive some meaningful observable quantities not depending on $\Lambda.$